# Connecting linux virtual machine on vmbox using putty

Tags: virtual-machine, putty

Hi i created a vm using oracle vm virtualbox on my windows. Once i start a vm can i connect externally from my windows using tools like putty ? because i tried connecting but putty does not allow me to do the same.

Guest OS : CentOS

Is it set up to accept incoming connections from PuTTY? (i.e. SSH? telnet? or what?) : not sure on how to configure the same.

Nw settings : Check below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fYIU.jpg)

What address have you tried to connect to? : I tried connecting to localhost.localdomain because thats why my vm returned when i typed hostname command.

Comment: What is the guest OS? Is it set up to accept incoming connections from PuTTY? (i.e. SSH? telnet? or what?). What are network settings for the guest in VirtualBox? What address have you tried to connect to? and why to this particular one? Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

I always use host only adapter with static ipaddresess for multiple guest vms's.

Although I never used NAT interface,I tested NAT interface on Oracle Linux guest o/s with NAT adapter for this demonstration and it worked.I have two adapters enabled (eth0 is Nat Adapter and eth1 is host only adapter)

- ** For NAT adapter**
- 1) On Guest VM get ipaddress with command ifconfig(as root user)
    or sudo ifconfig. 
    In my guest o/s the ipaddress is 10.0.2.15.[image: Ipaddress]
- 2)Disable firewall on guest o/s or add Nat interface to trusted interface
- 3)shutdown vm guest o/s
- 4) Go to NAT adapter click port forwarding button add host,guest ipaddress 
    and ports (see the image) [image: Nat Image]

  - 5) Start guest vm
  - 6) Set up putty terminal with ipaddress  127.0.0.1 and port 2222 (see the 
    image)
    [image: ssh]